# Merging two excel files into one files using python

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have tried using openpyxl, but I don't know which function could help me to append three worksheet into one. I found error with write this file into one

```
 import pandas as pd

 excel_names = ["/tmp/xlsx1.xlsx", "/tmp/xlsx2.xlsx"]
 pd.read_excel(excel_names, engine='openpyxl')
 excels = [pandas.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]
 frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]
 frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]
 combined = pandas.concat(frames)
 combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
 excl_merged.to_excel('total_food_sales.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: what error might you be getting?

Comment: are these files too big? (usually happens in Data science projects ) use batches

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite error when writing the file

Comment: @ImdadKhan :No small files with less than 1Mb

Comment: well then it's probably a problem in the last few rows of your script

Comment: check if the file names matches and are in the right directory

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite:Error is "No module named 'openpyxl.writer.write_only" Is there any name names to be included for this